# MySQL - Return number of views, or 0 if no row

Tags: mysql

I got the current query:

```
SELECT views FROM restaurant_views 
WHERE (restaurant_id=:rest_id) 
AND (date >= DATE_SUB(:date, INTERVAL 12 DAY))
```

It returns the number of views the last 12 days.
But sometimes when a restaurant has no views, let's say for 1 day, it will skip that row, returning only 11 rows instead of 12.

My question is:
How do I return 0 in that rows place if the restaurant has no views? (no row in the restaurant_views table)

Right now it's returning this: *(Some numbers missing because row was empty)*
1. 70
2. 40
5. 50
6. 40
7. 40
9. 20
10. 40
11. 40
12. 40

What I want is this:
1. 70
2. 40
**3. 0

4. 0**
5. 50
6. 40
7. 40
**8. 0**
9. 20
10. 40
11. 40
12. 50

Comment: the default value for "views" column is?

Comment: set 'views' default value to '0' and add to your query: `AND (views >= 0)`

Comment: If the restaurant has no views for that day, there is no row.

Comment: ok, mysql looks for number of views and if it's 0, don't return value? What is the default value for 'views' -> 0 or '' (empty) ? Do you have tried my solution?

Comment: no no no, I want it to return 0 if there is no row. The default value is not important. Check my edit.

Comment: Don't you have a typo in the 'where'? I think the "AND (:date >=  (:date - INTERVAL 12 DAY))" should read "AND (date >=  (:date - INTERVAL 12 DAY))" - one colon less.

Comment: @ptrk nope, it's working fine! (It's PDO, so the :rest_id is just a variable I set in PHP later)

Comment: Sorry, hit Enter too soon. To me it looks like the date condition is always true (:date is always greater than :date less 12 days). To see last 12 days from now, I'd use something like now() function.

Comment: Wow, you were right. Updated the code, thanks alot! Totally missed that one

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join with master table restaurant, if any.

```
SELECT r.id, IFNULL(rv.viewes, 0)
FROM   restaurant r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN restaurant_views rv 
ON     r.id = rv.id
WHERE
..//other conditions you need to add
```